# How to change ID's of <tr> and <td> of a table accordingly if one of the row is deleted

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with 5 rows. It should have the functionality of adding and deleting rows dynamically. Every row has 3 columns, `partNO`, `quantity` and a `button` to delete that specific row. Every row has an `id` as well as the `td` inside the row.

My question is if the second row is deleted, The `id`s of the successive rows should be decremented by 1 to the end of the table.

```
<tr id='1'>
    <td><input type="button" id="b1" width="10" value="D"/></td>    
    <td align="center" id='l1'><input type="text" id="t1"></td>
    <td align="center" id='r1'><input type="text" id="q1"></td>
</tr>
<tr id='2'>
    <td><input type="button" id="b2" width="10" value="D"/></td>    
    <td align="center" id='l2'><input type="text" id="t2"></td>
    <td align="center" id='r2'><input type="text" id="q2"></td>
</tr>
<tr id='3'>
    <td><input type="button" id="b3" width="10" value="D"/></td>    
    <td align="center" id='l3'><input type="text" id="t3"></td>
    <td align="center" id='r3'><input type="text" id="q3"></td>
</tr>
<tr id='4'>
    <td><input type="button" id="b4" width="10" value="D"/></td>    
    <td align="center" id='l4'> <input type="text" id="t4"></td>
    <td align="center" id='r4'><input type="text" id="q4"></td>
</tr>
<tr id='5'>
    <td><input type="button" id="b5" width="10" value="D"/></td>    
    <td align="center" id='l5'><input type="text" id="t5"></td>
    <td align="center" id='r5'><input type="text" id="q5"></td>
</tr>
```

So `onclick` of `b2` `tr id=2` should be removed entirely and the next row ID's should be decremented accordingly. ID's of buttons `tr td` should be changed. Any help on this?

Comment: This is why using incremental `id` is a bad idea. Use the same `class` for each row's `td`, and another for the `tr`. Then you can use traversal techniques to amend and `eq()` to figure out which row you're on without the need to amend `id` attributes when the table state changes.

Comment: My question is why must they be incremented, the only answer as far as I can see is somnething is using ID to infer order, stop that, problem solved.

Comment: Its an already existing system . On entering values and clicking submit, the values should be send to webservices individually. so i used incremental ID's

Comment: What kind of webservice looks at HTML element ids instead of field names?

Comment: I have to take all the values in a loop, convert it into wellformed xml and then pass it to webservice

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit annoying to do, especially if you have events bound to specific elements.  Something like this is what you want:

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
   var $toRemove = $(this).closest('tr');
   var id = $toRemove.attr('id');
   $toRemove.removeAttr('id');

   $toRemove.nextAll().each(function () {
      this.id = id++;
      //also update td IDs
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi, i'm just a novice. But don't you think that the line `this.id = id++;` should have `id--;` as all the `ID`s should be decremented after deleting.

Comment: @xan Say you click row 2, `id` starts at 2.  All rows are moved down, and their ids are updated to 2, 3, 4 ....  If you use `--` they would be updated to 2, 1, 0, -1....

Comment: Say initially there are `ID`s as `1,2,3,4,5`.
Now you delete `3`.
So, `1,2` remain the same but `4-->3` and `5-->4`.
But how can the decrement happen while you are using `id++`. I still can't get it.

Comment: @xan I'm not sure that I can explain it any more clearly.  `4` gets `3` from `id` (which at that point is `3`).  Then, `id++` makes `id` equal to `4`.  Then, `5` gets `4`.

Comment: Oh..sorry, sorry..my bad!! I got it. It is recursively incrementing to access those `ID`s below the one that will be `clicked`.

Comment: how to get the id's of td??

Comment: @SrikanthAtmakuri that's up to you to figure out; I can't write everything for you or you won't learn